# need iframe code for facebook like button

Tags: iframe

I am trying to create a like button for my weebly website.  Weebly advises to use the IFRAME code but when I select this option with the facebook web developer, no code appears.  What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=PUT_URL_HERE&amp;width&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

And replace the `PUT_URL_HERE` with the url of the page you'd like to have your users like.